# Visual C# datagridview binding to object not working

Tags: data-binding, visual-c#-express-2010

I've gone through a couple of different tutorials with a couple approaches, but all i get is an empty datagridview. The applicable part of the code is:

```
public partial class ViewRoster2 : Form
{
    public League vleague;
    public List<Player> vlist;
    public int selteam;

    public ViewRoster2(League myLeague)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        selteam = 0;
        vleague = myLeague;
        vlist = vleague.playerlist;
        dGrid1.DataSource = vlist;
    }
```

From what i understand from a tutorial, the Datagrid - dGrid1 -  should populate itself with columns based on object "Player" properties, and fill rows with each "Player" entry in the List<> - vlist.

But as said, all i get is a form with an empty datagridview.

Any help or push in the right direction appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I just followed the same kind of tutorial for binding a List of Objects to a DataGridView and got exactly the same issue as you.

As you didn't illustrate the definition of your "Player" object I'm not sure the cause was exactly the same, but in my case the issue was that my object definition didn't have a getter, so the DataSource was unable to retrieve the object properties to construct the View

For example, you will obtain an empty View if your define your object like this :

```
public class Player
{
    public string name;
    public int age;

    public Player(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

By adding for example { get; set; } then the View is getting populated :

```
public class Player
{
    public string name **{ get; set; }**
    public int age **{ get; set; }**

    public Player(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

I hope it will help other beginners like me ;-)